# How to get the tag from selected item

Tags: c#, listview, win-universal-app

Getting the `SelectedItem`'s `Tag` property when Item has been selected..

I have this in my `XAML`:

```
<ListView IsItemClickEnabled="True" x:Name="settigns_listView" Margin="15,270,0,0" ItemClick="settigns_listView_ItemClick">
   <ListViewItem Tag="credits" Margin="0,0,30,0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,3" BorderBrush="#FF353534" FontSize="26.667" Content="Credits"/>
   <ListViewItem Tag="reset" Margin="0,10,30,0" BorderThickness="0,0,0,3" BorderBrush="#FF353534" FontSize="26.667" Content="Reset game"/>
</ListView>
```

And within the `ItemClick` event I have this:

```
private void settigns_listView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
  ListViewItem listViewItem = settigns_listView.SelectedItem as ListViewItem;
  string data = listViewItem.Tag.ToString();
}
```

However for this line `string data = listViewItem.Tag.ToString();` I get this error "Object reference cannot be null" it seems my listViewItem is null, but i dont understand why?

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you set Tag value for all the ListViewItem when populating the listView?

Comment: also: this: `ListViewItem listViewItem = settigns_listView.SelectedItem as ListViewItem;` can raise that exception only if  `settigns_listView` is null. If not, it will simply assign null to your `ListViewItem listViewItem` variable

Comment: @GianPaolo All Tags are set.. and yes you are right, it raises the exception when accessing the tag as the listViewItem is null

Answer (score 0):

go with debugger and check:

- is settigns_listView.SelectedItem null when you access it?
- if not, is it a ListViewItem? (it should be...).

Maybe you need to register for `SelectionChanged` event of the listview instead of the `Click` event of the ListViewItem

Comment: The SelectedItem is null

Comment: I assume the .NET framework raises the event `ItemClick` before setting `SelectedItem` value. Play with different events of ListView and ListViewItem, add some `Debug.Write(string.format("event X - selectedItem = {0}", settigns_listView.SelectedItem);` (or some message more detailed)
Check when it changes.

Comment: SelectedionChanged does not get called

Comment: Did you remove the line raising the exception? Just write some debug code that does not throw exception, so you can understand event order and when SelectedItem property get changed